# Ag-grid Pivot "Remove Duplicates" function like in Excel

Tags: javascript, duplicates, pivot, ag-grid, cartesian-product

I am using plain JS ag-grid in my application. I need to use pivot mode for displaying my data, but I am missing the "remove duplicates" function that for example excel has.

I will try to give you an example:

In my backend, data looks like this

```
[
  {
    property1: "prop1",
    property2: "prop2",
    items: [ "item1", "item2" ],
    fruits: [ "fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"],
    colors: [ "color1", "color2"]
  },
  {
    property1: "prop1",
    property2: "prop2",
    items: [ "item1", "item2" ],
    fruits: [ "fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3" ],
    colors: [ "color1", "color2" ]
  }, ...
]
```

All properties should be able to be selected as either row group or pivot column in my grid.
To accomplish this, I build the cartesian of this array, which looks like this:

```
[
  {
     property1: "prop1",
     property2: "prop2",
     item: "item1",
     fruit: "fruit2",
     color: "color1"
  },
  {
     property1: "prop1",
     property2: "prop2",
     item: "item1",
     fruit: "fruit2",
     color: "color3" 
  }, ... 
]
```

This already works fine, and I get perfectly denormalized data for my ag-grid.

However when I have for example "items" set as row group and "fruits" as pivot column, I will get duplicates of the same object, because there are multiple entries in the array with the only difference in the color property, which is not relevant in this pivot.

If I remember correctly, there is a "remove duplicates" function in excel pivot table. Is there anything like this provided by ag-grid?

If not, I am grateful for any other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you were able to get it working?

Comment: yes, but I have implemented my own logic. In the valueGetter I generate a string which acts like a key that is used in the custom aggregation function